# How to extract elements from Presto ARRAY(MAP(VARCHAR, VARCHAR))

Tags: sql, arrays, json, dictionary, presto

I have an array of maps and data format is ARRAY(MAP(VARCHAR, VARCHAR)); I'd like to extract "id" and "description" features from this "Item_Details" column:

```
+-----------+-------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--+--+
| Company   | Country     | Item_Details                                                                                                                                               |  |  |
+===========+=============+============================================================================================================================================================+==+==+
| Apple     | US          | [{"created":"2019-09-15","product":"apple watch", "amount": "$7,900"},{"created":"2022-09-19","product":"iPhone", "amount": "$78,300"},{"created":"2021-01-13","product":"Macbook Pro", "amount": "$163,980"}] |  |  |
| Google    | US          | [{"created":"2020-07-15","product":"Nest", "amount": "$78,300"},{"created":"2021-07-15","product":"Google phone", "amount": "$178,900"}]                             |  |  |
+-----------+-------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--+
```

My expected outputs would be:

```
+-----------+-------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--+--+
| Company   | Country     | Item_Details                                                                                                                                               |  |  |
+===========+=============+============================================================================================================================================================+==+==+
| Apple     | US          | ["product":["apple watch", "iPhone", "Macbook Pro"], "amount":[ "$7,900", "$78,300","$163,980"] |  |  |
| Google    | US          | ["product":["Nest", "Google phone"], "amount": "$78,300", "$178,900"]                             |  |  |
+-----------+-------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--+
```

or

```
+-----------+-------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--+--+
| Company   | Country     | Product    | Amount                                                                                                                                               |  |  |
+===========+=============+============================================================================================================================================================+==+==+
| Apple     | US          | apple watch | $7,900   |  |  |
| Apple     | US          | iPhone      | $78,300  |  |  |
| Apple     | US          | Macbook Pro | $163,980 |  |  |
  ...
+-----------+-------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--+
```

I tried `element_at(Item_Details, 'product')` and `json_extract_scalar(Item_Details, '$.product')` but received error "Unexpected parameters (array(map(varchar,varchar)), varchar(23)) for function element_at. "

Any suggestions is much appreciated! Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second one you can `unnest` the array and access elements of map:

```sql
-- sampel data
WITH dataset(Company, Country, Item_Details) AS (
    values ('Google', 'US', array[
        map(array['created', 'product', 'amount'], array['2019-09-15', 'Nest', '$78,300']),
        map(array['created', 'product', 'amount'], array['2019-09-16', 'Nest1', '$79,300'])
    ])
)

-- query
select Company,
       Country,
       m['product'] product,
       m['amount'] amount
from dataset d,
unnest(Item_Details) as t(m);
```

Output:

| Company | Country | product | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Google | US | Nest | $78,300 |
| Google | US | Nest1 | $79,300 |